# How to pass form inputs with dynamic fields (bunch of them) from child window(opened using window.open) to parent

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I know this question has been asked and answered. I have lot of dynamic input variables in the child window(using window.open) . The submit button is in the parent window that submits everything to server. How to access form elements in the child window in the server side? I have to set the child window params in the parent window I guess. How to do for dynamic elements?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: Just serialise the form and execute a parent function